# How to share static object across processes in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, caching, static

Background:

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399957/static-provider-dictionary-design) about creating a cached provider structure for my WCF service. I've implemented that design now, but what I've noticed in testing, is that the providers aren't actually being cached. How do I know this? I added the following debug-level logging to my service:

```
private static readonly IDictionary<string, XmlLoaderProviderBase> _providerDictionary =
    new Dictionary<string, XmlLoaderProviderBase>();

public void Load(LoadRequest loadRequest)
{
    XmlLoaderProviderBase xmlLoader;
    if (_providerDictionary.ContainsKey(loadRequest.TransferTypeCode))
    {
        // Use cached provider...
        xmlLoader = _providerDictionary[loadRequest.TransferTypeCode];

        Logger.Log.DebugFormat("Found cached provider: {0} for transfer type: {1}",
            xmlLoader.GetType(), loadRequest.TransferTypeCode);
    }
    else
    {
        // Instantiate provider for the first time; add provider to cache...
        xmlLoader = XmlLoaderProviderFactory.CreateProvider(loadRequest.TransferTypeCode);
        _providerDictionary.Add(loadRequest.TransferTypeCode, xmlLoader);

        Logger.Log.DebugFormat("Instantiating provider: {0} for transfer type: {1}",
            xmlLoader.GetType(), loadRequest.TransferTypeCode);
    }
    xmlLoader.Load(loadRequest);
}
```

And what I notice, is that no matter how many times I call the service, a provider is always instantiated (it never finds the cached version). Thankfully log4net is pretty helpful, and it shows that each call to the service runs in it's own unique process (i.e. it has a unique process ID). So as is, the providers will never be cached. How can I get this to actually cache providers, and read that dictionary across processes? Is this even possible?

I also read similar questions to this here on SO, and I notice the *InstanceContextMode* setting. I don't think I want this, because I think that will hurt performance (am I wrong? way off?) In a nut shell, my desire is to share the *_providerDictionary* across all processes/service instances... please help!

Comment: WCF service calls do _not_ run in separate processes.

Comment: There's no such thing as static objects. You can have static classes and static members

Comment: @JohnSaunders -I'll buy that for a dollar, but a couple of things: 1) successive calls to the service show a different PID each time, and 2) the line that checks to see if the provider already exists never evaluates to true. Care to elaborate on your position and provide me with some more insight here?

Comment: How do you host your WCF service? In IIS or self hosting? I think it depends mainly on your host whether the service process is restarted or not. I would use the InstanceContextMode. Never worry about performance unless you measure it.

Comment: If you're getting a new process each time, then you had better find out what's crashing your original process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to steal @slfan's comment:

Use

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

Default InstanceContextMode is PerSession.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into creating a custom caching framework using System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache / MemoryCache.  To my knowledge this should be accessible across processes.  It is also threadsafe.

See the following links:

http://technovivek.blogspot.com/2013/08/c-in-memory-cache-using-net-40-object.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290935/Using-MemoryCache-in-Net